# Cannot recycle a Sitecore CMS Item from a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, sitecore, recycle

I am using a Windows Service which does cleanup jobs on Sitecore Items (inactive or old products) and when I am trying to delete them I cannot.

```
if (qItem != null)
{
 qItem.Recycle();
}
```

Relevat StackTrace is:

```
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace:   at Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler.OnItemDeleted(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemDeleted(Object sender, ItemDeletedEventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_ItemDeleted(Object sender, ExecutedEventArgs`1 e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuted()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.RaiseDeletedItem(Item item, ID parentId, Boolean result)
   at Sitecore.Data.Archiving.Archive.NotifyItemDeleted(Item item, ID parentId)
   at Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.DoArchiveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, Guid archivalId)
   at Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.DoArchiveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, Guid archivalId)
   at Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.ArchiveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Recycle()
```

I mention again that this error I get only if I recycle an item from a Windows Service. Same recycle works ok from Web app.

In Web app I am logged in into sitecore and user is admin, so he has some rights.

In Windows Service the user (Sitecore.Context.User) is `"default\Anonymous"`.

To bypass security checks I surrounded the Recycle call inside a SecurityDisabler using but without results.

Do I need to login into Sitecore from my Windows Service? If yes, how can I do that?

Or is there another way to recycle/delete Sitecore Item from a non-web application?

Here is the code that runs and throws a Access Denied Exception (it does not run inside a SecurityDisabler context):

[image: Recycle item directly, not inside a security disabler.]
Here is the code that recycles item inside a SecurityDisabler context. No Access Denied exception now, but a "Object reference not set to an instance" exception.

[image: Recycle item inside a SecurityDisabler context]

Comment: You could try the web service. You can find it under /sitecore/shell/WebService

Answer (score 4):

Looking in Reflector at the method (`Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler.OnItemDeleted`) which is throwing the exception, it would appear that your null reference is likely the TaskDatabase.

```
protected void OnItemDeleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    Error.AssertNotNull(item, "No item in parameters");
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        Globals.TaskDatabase.RemoveItemTasks(item);
    }
}
```

I assume for your windows service, you have an App.config with a stripped down Sitecore configuration. You should ensure that the `/sitecore/configuration/TaskDatabase` element is in your Sitecore config.

Comment: There is a TaskDatabase in config file:

    <TaskDatabase type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)TaskDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <param connectionStringName="core"/>
    </TaskDatabase>

Comment: I also looked for the executed code using Reflector but could not figure out what variable is null.

Answer (score 1):

When we install a Sitecore instance, we are provided with a web service which is exposed under the same domain as the Sitecore application

http://sitedomain.com/sitecore/shell/webservice/service.asmx

This service has all the methods you need to work with Sitecore API.

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with a standalone service using **Sitecore APIs**.

I was using the **BucketManager** to Sync an item bucket, which ended up invoking the same `item.Delete()` method that Recycle calls, so my stack trace led me to the same spot.

The **TaskDatabase** was defined in the `web.config` I was using, but I decided the `Load()` method on Globals was never getting called, so I was never initializing the Task Database field with anything from Config.

In the constructor of the object I invoked the delete from, I included the line:

```
Sitecore.Globals.Load();
```

This solved my issue.